# Get board.vid and board.pid value in code

Tags: usb

I'm working on a custom Arduino core based on the teensy code and want to be able to get the board USB VID/PID from boards.txt, as in .board.vid and .board.pid

From what I can tell, Arduino already does this for the Leonardo and similar since if I change the VID/PID in boards.txt then the sketch will run with those values.

But how do I actually get at them? Right now the code I have has hard coded values, but it would be great to make them dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor will sub in the values for the names "USB_PID" and "USB_VID"

this line in "platform.txt" grabs them and makes build flags for them:

```
build.usb_flags=-DUSB_VID={build.vid} -DUSB_PID={build.pid} '-DUSB_MANUFACTURER={build.usb_manufacturer}' '-DUSB_PRODUCT={build.usb_product}'
```

the -D* option in the build is equivalent to the following lines being in the code

```
#define USB_VID /*value of build.vid*/
#define USB_PID /*value of build.pid*/
#define USB_MANUFACTURER /*value of build.usb_manufacturer*/
#define USB_PRODUCT /*value of build.usb_product*/
```

If you are curious, they are used by the libraries in "USBCore.cpp". Also, they will never be defined for devices they don't apply to.

Comment: Weird though... could not get manufacturer and product to work. VID/PID worked fine though.

Comment: That is odd. What version of arduino are you using? That came from 1.5.8

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find platform.txt... I'm using 1.0.5
I swear there was a reason I hadn't upgraded to the beta yet, but can't remember what that was at the moment... think it was incompatible with something I needed.